# Angular: Allow access to component member by template only

Tags: angular

This has been bugging me for a very long time and I can't find a satisfying answer.

Say we have the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.scss']
})
export class FooComponent {

  constructor() {
  }

  respondToEventFromTemplate() {
    // do something...
  }
}
```

Since templates are not members of a component, **respondToEventFromTemplate** must be made *public* for the code to pass AOT.

However, say we have the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar',
  template: '<app-foo #foo></app-foo>',
  styleUrls: ['./bar.component.scss']
})
export class FooComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  
  @ViewChild('foo') fooComponent: FooComponent;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.fooComponent.respondToEventFromTemplate();
  }


}
```

This code is completely valid but breaks encapsulation. A method that responds to an event in the template of component **Foo** shouldn't be accessible by component **Bar** and therefore should be made *private*.

So my question is: what is the solution or workaround that allows me to make a component member only accessible in its template and inaccessible anywhere else?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no solution for it, there is a issue for this in Angular repo.

Comment: @HTN Thought so. I've looked into it for hours with no success. Thank you.